# Vuex: unknown action type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I am having massive problems with vuex. Getters, actions and mutations don't get found with no obvious reason. In the example below, fetchFacilities is being recognized and executed, but addFacility throws [vuex] unknown action type: addFacility:
(from store.ts)

```
//...
actions: {
  addFaciltiy: async function (context, fac: CFacility) {
    await axios.post('/db/facilities', fac)
  },
  fetchFacilities: async function (context, actions) {
    axios.get('/db/facilities').then((response) => response.data.forEach((element: CFacility) => {
    context.commit('addFacility', element);
  }));
}
//...
```

(from the vue component)

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { CFacility } from "./model";
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default Vue.extend({
    //...
      methods: mapActions(["fetchFacilities", "addFacility"]),
    //...
    created() {
      this.fetchFacilities("a");
      this.addFacility(
        new CFacility(//..)
    );
}}
```

I am using the autogenerated store.ts. I have read through countless posts of people messing up modules and their namespaces, which I don't use. I tried arrow notation for the actions, rewrote the actions multiple times and accessed them via dispatch and via mapActions.

Comment: There's a typo on your definition of `addFaciltiy` note the *Faciltiy*

Comment: Flagging to close this as **Off-topic due to typo** based on [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56584641/vuex-unknown-action-type/56631763#comment99747711_56584641) and [OP's confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56631763/8239061).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a simple typo, muchas gracias @daniel ormeño

Answer (score 0):

Try to put ellipsis before mapActions:

```
methods: ...mapActions(["fetchFacilities", "addFacility"]),
```